# In Pentaho, how to compare first value with second value in a column if source data is in CSV file

Tags: javascript, pentaho

when i try to compare first value with second value in a single column, i couldn't make progress on this. Please help me to accomplish this logic.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the step "Analytic Query" you can get the previous value (or next) from a column